# How to install offline a new version of python package from a .egg folder?

Tags: python, anaconda, statsmodels, egg

I am trying to install the dev version of statsmodels in a machine with no internet connection. I have downloaded and installed the package on my own machine (tested and working fine) and I have copied the resulting folder under `Anaconda\Lib\site-packages` on the offline machine.

I also kept the existing statsmodels folder (since this is what happened on my machine) so that the structure in both machines looks like

```
site-packages\
    statsmodels
    statsmodels-0.6.1-py2.7.egg-info
    statsmodels-0.8.0-py3.5-win-amd64.egg\
        EGG-INFO
        statsmodels
```

The inner statsmodels folder (the one under 0.8.0) contains the newest version that I want to import. In order for the importer to pick up the correct version I replicated a file that appeared on my machine called `easy-install.pth` with the following content

```
import sys; sys.__plen = len(sys.path)
./statsmodels-0.8.0-py3.5-win-amd64.egg
import sys; new = sys.path[sys.__plen:]; del sys.path[sys.__plen:]; p = getattr(sys, '__egginsert', 0); sys.path[p:p] = new; sys.__egginsert = p + len(new)
```

Now the importer picks up the correct version (0.8.0) but it fails to import the DLLs giving me the following error

```
    C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\statsmodels-0.8.0-py3.5-win-amd64.egg\statsmodels\tsa\statespace\tools.py in set_mode(compatibility)
     59     if not compatibility:
     60         from scipy.linalg import cython_blas
---> 61         from . import (_representation, _kalman_filter, _kalman_smoother,
     62                        _simulation_smoother, _tools)
     63         compatibility_mode = False

C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\statsmodels-0.8.0-py3.5-win-amd64.egg\statsmodels\tsa\statespace\_representation.py in <module>()
      6     print(__name__,__file__)
      7     imp.load_dynamic(__name__,__file__)
----> 8 __bootstrap__()

C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\statsmodels-0.8.0-py3.5-win-amd64.egg\statsmodels\tsa\statespace\_representation.py in __bootstrap__()
      5     __loader__ = None; del __bootstrap__, __loader__
      6     print(__name__,__file__)
----> 7     imp.load_dynamic(__name__,__file__)
      8 __bootstrap__()

ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

I have checked the variable `__file__` on the last function call and it points to the DLL `_representation.cp35-win_amd64.pyd` which exists under the statespace folder.

Anyone knows a workaround for this or how I can tell the importer to find the missing module?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you to use `pip` to list all required libraries and download them, then distribute the downloaded libraries and install.

### List all required libraries

From a server/workstation which has the same configuration as the target server (same OS, same system-wide Python).

Create a new empty virtualenv and install [statsmodels](http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/) as usual:

```
virtualenv venv
source venv/bin/activate
pip install statsmodels
```

Then list all required packages with [pip freeze](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_freeze/):

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

### Download all required libraries

Create a directory to store all eggs/wheels, and use [pip download](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_download/) to download the libraries:

```
mkdir libs
cd libs/
pip download --no-deps -r requirements.txt
```

### Distribute onto your target server

Copy the `libs` directory to your target server.

Create a virtualenv and install from your `libs` directory:

```
virtualenv venv
source venv/bin/activate
pip install --find-links libs/ statsmodels
```

It should work.